# ipysheet question about update cell attribute

Tags: python, ipywidgets

My code here

```
import ipysheet
mysheet = ipysheet.sheet(rows=2, columns=2)
mysheet
c = cell(0,0,1, background_color = 'red')
```

I want to change `background_color`, I expect to do something like this

```
c.background_color = 'yellow'
```

Or later

```
mysheet[0, 0].background_color = 'yellow'
```

instead of construct a new object

```
c = cell(c.row_start, c.column_start, c.value, background_color = 'yellow')
```

Excuse me if I make a *read-doc-for-me* issue. But I didn't find method I expect. If there isn't, could anyone explain? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the [source code](https://ipysheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/ipysheet/easy.html#cell) of `cell` method you can find, that `cell` method returns instance of `ipysheet.sheet.Cell` class. Background color is set as a property of `style` parameter of this class. You can change this property dynamicaly by assigning a specified color to value if this property:

```
>>> import ipysheet
>>> from ipysheet.easy import cell
>>> mysheet = ipysheet.sheet(rows=2, columns=2)
>>> c = cell(0,0,1, background_color = 'red')
>>> type(c)
ipysheet.sheet.Cell
>>> print(c.style['backgroundColor'])
red
>>> c.style['backgroundColor'] = 'blue'
>>> print(c.style['backgroundColor'])
blue
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems, that setting the property to another value isn't change background color of sheet because the sheet's widget can't get state dynamically. You can update state by using `send_state()` method of cell instance:

```
c.style['backgroundColor'] = 'blue'
c.send_state()

# or by position in mysheet
mysheet[0, 0].style['backgroundColor'] = 'blue'
mysheet[0, 0].send_state()
```

After that cell of the sheet changes background color.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I fully regenerate your code and I totally agree. But if you just type `mysheet`. You will notice sheet's color doesn't change, even attribute's value has changed. The sheet's color will actually change only if you re-construct cell with same location and update color.(To my knowledge).

Comment: Hello, @KeZhang! After some research, I found a possible solution to the problem and describe it in 'update' section.

Comment: Nice. that did work. Also I find that c.style = {'backgroundColor': 'yellow'} will work instead of c.style['backgroundColor'] = 'yellow. I feel they should be same, right?

Comment: @KeZhang, hello! Yes, they work the same. 'style' property is a collection of key-value pairs. One of them is 'backgroundColor'. In case of c.style = {'backgroundColor': 'yellow'} you reassign property to dict with only one key ('backgroundColor') and other attributes is dropped (if there was other attributes). But assigning value to 'backgroundColor' key is a more relevant option because it does not influence on other attributes in style property.